# Data Recovery using EasyUS Data Recovery

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted a 60gb folder from my 1TB HDD. The hdd is not corrupted so i decided to use the deep scan method of easyus data recovery which i have used in the past and successfully found my files. However, it is taking so much time to finish. When i deleted my files i turned off the computer, removed the hdd and put it on another pc using a USB cable. My questions are: Is their a chance of burning my hdd since it will be scanning for over 10 hours? If i stop the scan will i reduce my chances of finding the data (since it is only scanning not writing)? What do you suggest me since i only deleted them and the hdd is just fine?

Comment: Wait until the scan finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the disk running for 10 hours or more, since it is not a problematic disk.
If you stop it, it will not reduce your chance of finding your data, unless you write something on the disk afterwards.
I don't know why you wish to stop it but if you do, when you scan the disk again you should first try without the deep scan feature, since your disk has not been formatted or heavily used after your accidental deletion. This will save you a lot of time.

Comment: It is producing a bit high temperature but if you say that it is okay i will leave it as is. To be honest i didn't look the files carefully in the quick scan so i am thinking of stopping it and go again to the quick scan.. i will see how it goes...